# Using an HTML string input, can I save that string and pass it on as parameters(java) in an PHP exec() command?

Tags: java, php, html, css, forms

Currently, I have a java `.class` file that I want to run when a button is pressed and `PHP exec()` command calls it.

Say I have this in a .class file:

```
class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = args[0];
    System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

Now I want PHP to execute this java using the `exec()` function. However, this class file needs parameters. I want to feed parameters through a form and submit button.

To the visitors, upon loading the site they would see the average form + submit:

```html
<form action="action_page.php">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Once they hit the submit button, I want the button to call PHP command

`exec(java test username lastname)`

given "username" and "lastname" is generated by the visitor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add `method="post"` to your form:

```
<form action="action_page.php" method="post">
```

Then on submit you will be able to access the form inputs using the `$_POST` variable. Make sure you call [`escapeshellarg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on user input variables.

```
$username = escapeshellarg($_POST['username']);
$lastname = escapeshellarg($_POST['lastname']);
```

And then you can use `exec()`:

```
exec("java test $username $lastname");
```